# Snort (Windows): why my local rules don't show on console?

Tags: windows, rules, snort

- Snort 2.9.14 in Windows system.
- Local rules to test in the file `local.rules`:

  ```
  alert tcp any any -> any any (msg:"TCP test"; sid:2000001; rev:1;)
  alert udp any any -> any any (msg:"UDP test"; sid:2000002; rev:1;)
  ```
- `include $RULE_PATH/local.rules` in `snort.conf` OK, uncommented.
- Snort start with:

  ```
  snort -i1 -c c:\snort\etc\snort.conf -l c:\snort\log -K ascii -k none -A console
  ```
- Snort count the local rules in initialization.
- Console show all other alerts while navigating but not the local ones. Why? How can I fix this?